# Pushing results from `any?` and `include?` into an array

Tags: ruby

This:

```
arry = %w[cat dog fish]
arry.any? {|s| pp s.include?('sh')}
```

outputs:

```
false
false
true
```

When I try to push elements into an array by doing this,

```
tester = []
arry = %w[cat dog fish]
arry.any? {|s| tester << s.include?('sh')}

pp tester
```

it outputs:

```
[false]
```

only one element is pushed. Not sure why I can't push the results from an `include?` into an array.

How can I get all the results into the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) immediately exits once the block returns `truthy` value.

I am unsure why would you ever use `any?` for this usecase, but what’s happening is: on the first iteration the block returns an array which is truthy.

Use `#each_with_object` or even simple `#map` instead:

```
arry.each_with_object([]) { |s, tester| tester << s.include?('sh') }
arry.map { |s| s.include?('sh') }
```

---

My fave:

```
arry.map(&/sh/.method(:!~)).map(&:!)
```